# Calling XSD from CMake

Tags: xsd, cmake

I'm working on a project that is partially generated from an XSD schema using codesynthesis. I have used the FindXSD.cmake at the following address to have CMake properly search for the XSD header:
http://wiki.codesynthesis.com/uploads/8/86/FindXSD.cmake.gz

This FindXSD.cmake sets the XSD_EXECUTABLE variable, which I would like to use to also generate the code from the schema prior to building any target (the main target of the project is a library), but being unfamiliar with CMake, I have a hard time understanding how to integrate such a custom command.

Here is what I did so far:

```
add_library (mylibrary ${MY_PROJECT_SRC})

add_custom_command(TARGET mylibrary PRE_BUILD
                COMMAND "${XSD_EXECUTABLE} cxx-tree --type-naming knr 
                -- hxx-suffix .hpp --cxx-suffix .cpp 
                ${MY_PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/model/Model.xsd")
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything and besides, if it did, I wouldn't know where the files are generated (the command should generate Model.hpp and Model.cpp), so I don't know what commands to add to have Model.cpp being compiled within the target library and Model.hpp being found by other source files that require it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`add_custom_target()`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_target) with `ALL` keyword:

```
add_custom_target(xsdgen
                  COMMAND ${XSD_EXECUTABLE} cxx-tree --type-naming knr
                  --hxx-suffix .hpp --cxx-suffix .cpp
                  ${MY_PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/model/Model.xsd)
```

This would add this command to the list of **all** targets. Now you need to make sure that this target will be built before **mylibrary**:

```
add_dependencies(mylibrary xsdgen)
```

There is another way - using `add_custom_command` to define a rule for producing `Model.hpp` and `Model.cpp`. In this case CMake would compute dependencies for you: whenever you use `Model.{c,h}pp` as `add_{library, executable}` argument, CMake would set your custom command as target's dependency.

This is, actually, preferred way for doing stuff like generating files, as it allows CMake to skip files, that have been generated already. On the contrary, `add_custom_target` will be built each time you run `make`.